# Replacing numerical value with "x" or "$" in between/end in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

I was working on my class assignment, and there is this point in it.

> 7. Display your mobile number in following format: xxxxxx5678 (5678 is last 4 digit of mobile no)
> 8. Display the mobile number in this format: $$$5678$$$ (5678 is middle 4 digit of mobile no)

I tried using MySQL's replace() function but that won't work either. It only works for point 7, but I don't know how to use it for point 8.
I tried multiple ways, but that didn't work either.

Comment: string length is fixed or variable? format: xxxxxx5678, the query will be written accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the 7 question, you may use `RIGHT`:

```sql
SELECT CONCAT('xxxxxx', RIGHT(number, 4)) AS phone_number
FROM yourTable;
```

For the 8 question, consider this:

```sql
SELECT CONCAT('$$$', SUBSTR(number, 4, 4), '$$$') AS phone_number
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: top of the class for you:-)